# Marking "make private or Serializable" error as false-positive

Tags: java, serialization, sonarqube

In one of my Serializable class, Sonar is complaining, "Make empName transient or Serializable" for below property.
I changed Object to Serializable (`protected Map<String, Serializable> empName;`). Now its giving "Make empName private or Serializable" error. 
My question is, can I mark it as false positive because if the type of the value is Serializable then Java will 
give error either at compile time or runtime ?

Property Declaration:

```
protected Map<String, Object> empName;
```

Thanks

Comment: It's complaining that `Map` may not be serializable. Change it to a serializable Map type, e.g. `HashMap`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks for the reply. Yes I can change it to HashMap but my question was whether I can mark it as false positive

Comment: Why particularly does the class need to be serialized? (at least why using Java Serializables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  It is not a false positive, in general.  The interface `Map` does not implement `Serializable`.  Therefore `empName` *could* refer to a non-serializable map, which would lead to a runtime exception.

In some contexts, this could be a false positive.  For example, if can proved that `empName` is never assigned a non-serializable map, then this is a false positive.

However, since you have declared the field as `protected` and not `final`, you would need to analyze the class containing this declaration *and all possible subclasses*, and check all assignments to the field.   (Indeed, if you want to be really thorough you also need for reflective assignments.)

Comment: @cricket_007 - since the OP ignored that suggestion from Sonar, I am assuming that the OP wants to serialize the `empName` field.  Anyway, the question is whether this is a false positive.